# Android app crashes when loading html using inappwebview package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `flutter_inappwebview` package and rendering html data. for iOS it is working fine but not android some html crashes the app.

The error I am getting is

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/bluejay/bluejay:13/TQ1A.230205.002/9471150:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1.0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-03-14 00:34:58.130275054+0530
Process uptime: 46s
Cmdline: com.saaslabs.helpwise
pid: 4214, tid: 4312, name: RenderThread  >>> com.saaslabs.helpwise <<<
uid: 10288
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: invalid chunk state when deallocating address 0x200007335a540d0'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000010d8  x2  0000000000000006  x3  00000071deb582e0
    x4  0000000000808080  x5  0000000000808080  x6  0000000000808080  x7  8080808080808080
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007520b6a9e0  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000007520bac370
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 000000000488c84a  x15 0000000000000030
    x16 0000007520c19d50  x17 0000007520bf4eb0  x18 00000071daa76000  x19 0000000000001076
    x20 00000000000010d8  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 00000071deb587b0
    x24 b400007315abbc30  x25 0000000000000001  x26 0000000000000000  x27 00000071deb59000
    x28 b400007445ad79a8  x29 00000071deb58360
    lr  0000007520b9c1c8  sp  00000071deb582c0  pc  0000007520b9c1f4  pst 0000000000001000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000531f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
      #01 pc 00000000000418b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+8) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
      #02 pc 0000000000042260  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::ScopedErrorReport::~ScopedErrorReport()+32) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
      #03 pc 0000000000042604  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportInvalidChunkState(scudo::AllocatorAction, void*)+116) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
      #04 pc 0000000000044164  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+308) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
      #05 pc 00000000007663d4  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (vulkan::image::~image()+212) (BuildId: 556d636a49f8475a)
      #06 pc 00000000007653d8  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (vkDestroyImage+40) (BuildId: 556d636a49f8475a)
      #07 pc 0000000000630da0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (GrAHardwareBufferUtils::VulkanCleanupHelper::~VulkanCleanupHelper()+32) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #08 pc 0000000000630d64  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (GrAHardwareBufferUtils::delete_vk_image(void*)+20) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #09 pc 00000000006f6808  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkSurface::MakeFromAHardwareBuffer(GrDirectContext*, AHardwareBuffer*, GrSurfaceOrigin, sk_sp<SkColorSpace>, SkSurfaceProps const*, bool)+392) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #10 pc 0000000000584bac  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::VulkanSurface::dequeueNativeBuffer()+796) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #11 pc 0000000000584664  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::VulkanManager::dequeueNextBuffer(android::uirenderer::renderthread::VulkanSurface*)+52) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #12 pc 0000000000427e24  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+340) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #13 pc 00000000004b5ab4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (std::__1::__function::__func<android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::postAndWait()::$_0, std::__1::allocator<android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::postAndWait()::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() (.__uniq.264041412789356548918088680803242235290.c1671e787f244890c877724752face20)+644) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #14 pc 000000000058b504  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+644) (BuildId: 8be5452a9e9eca8a9f829a555addfa75)
      #15 pc 00000000000147f0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+528) (BuildId: 0b4a793fa8045c04066d988c68bac8bb)
      #16 pc 00000000000c226c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
      #17 pc 0000000000054a30  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
Lost connection to device.
```

I checked all issues and resources

Comment: It seems like a memory allocation dellocation problem with com.saaslabs.helpwise

Comment: yes that's the app package name

Comment: have you tried with another url inside the webview?

Comment: tried flutter_webview package but the issue is same